# How can write.csv and read.csv preserve the data format?

Tags: r, format

I have a dataframe which contains majority of the columns as numeric. Then I use this command to write to  csv file

```
    write.csv(df, "mydf.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

Then later I read in the file using:

```
    df = read.csv("mydf.csv", header = F, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors=F,dec=".")
```

Then as I checked the data formate using

```
   sapply(df, class)
```

all the columns change into character.  If I don't put stringsAsFactors=F,
all the columns change into factor.
I could manually change  columns into  numeric later. I just wonder if there is a method I could preserve  the data format at least for the majority columns while write or read csv file.  Is there better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `write.csv` will include headers, but when you are importing them you are telling R that there are no headers. It's likely that those headers are non-numeric which triggers the switch to character. So either turn off the headers in the `write.csv()` or set `header=TRUE` in the `read.csv()`